how do i make my own live candlestick chart with python?
Im trying to create a live candlestick chart that gets the price from just scraping the live gold price from a website. I'm not sure but i think that is the only way of getting live forex data without paying. I was thinking about updating a candle with the scraped data for 15 minutes and then close that candle and create a new candle so it works like TradingView. Is it possible to create something like that using matplotlib and are there any recommendations for creating something like that?
i have made a simple candlestick chart that gets historical gold price data from a csv as an example for the matplotlib candlestick chart thingy.
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("XAUUSD15.csv", delimiter='\t', header=None)
df.columns = ["Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"]
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

style = "yahoo"
last_candles = df.iloc[-150:]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 3.9))
mpf.plot(last_candles, type='candle', style=style, 
         volume=False, ax=ax, ylabel='',
         xrotation=0, datetime_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
ax.set_facecolor('#101010')
fig.patch.set_facecolor('xkcd:black')
ax.grid(True, color='black', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='white')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


Welcome to stack overflow! You are already using mplfinance, so I guess you already have a good idea how to create a candle stick chart. What exactly do you want to know? How to scrape data of a website? How to transform the data into a format suitable for mpf? If there is a better way than the fixed 15 minute interval? etc. etc. - please clarify :)

It sounds like you want to do what matplotlib calls "animation" ... that is, to have a plot update periodically (for example once every 15 minutes, or even once a minute).
The gist of animation is this:

You write a function that will be called periodically to update your plot.  This function will need to have access to the mplfinance Axes objects.  Each time it is called it takes the latest data values, appends them to the previous data values dataframe, and plots all the data on the same existing set of Axes that were originally plotted by mplfinance.
After you have written this "animate" function, you then need to have your code import matplotlib.animation as animation.
Then create your original plot with some data, but don't display it yet (in other words set, returnfig=True or use external axes mode when calling mpf.plot).
Next, call animation.FuncAnimation(figure,your_animate_function,interval).
Finally call mpf.show() to display the plot.

After the plot is displayed your animation function will be called every interval milliseconds.
Your animation function will have to have access to, or know how to get, then next set of data to plot from your scrape.  You can have the animation function itself call the scraper function, or have a separate process that does the scraping and simply have your animation function check to see if there is any newly scraped data available.

important:
There are 4 different examples in the examples folder of the mplfinance repository.
Those are:

mpf_animation_demo1.py
mpf_animation_demo2.py
mpf_animation_growingcandle.py
mpf_animation_macd.py

You should be able to run each file by:

first clone the repository, then
cd into the mplfinance/examples/ foler, and then
run python <filename> (for example, python mpf_animation_demo1.py).

Try running each file and, then read the comments and the code in each file carefully to understand what's going on.

For further understanding of matplotlib animations see also using matplotlib animations and matplotlib animation reference.
